# Rspec, Capybara, Guard - uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base (NameError)

Tags: activerecord, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

When I start guard and save a rspec request, I always get this error,

I referred to this tutorial, http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test

**uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base (NameError)**

See below,

```
/home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/audited-activerecord-3.0.0/lib/audited/adapters/active_record/audit.rb:16:in `<module:ActiveRecord>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base (NameError)
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/audited-activerecord-3.0.0/lib/audited/adapters/active_record/audit.rb:6:in `<module:Adapters>'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/audited-activerecord-3.0.0/lib/audited/adapters/active_record/audit.rb:5:in `<module:Audited>'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/audited-activerecord-3.0.0/lib/audited/adapters/active_record/audit.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/audited-activerecord-3.0.0/lib/audited/adapters/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/audited-activerecord-3.0.0/lib/audited-activerecord.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/think/jonathan/organizor/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/think/jonathan/organizor/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/think/jonathan/organizor/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/think/jonathan/organizor/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/think/jonathan/organizor/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/think/jonathan/organizor/spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/think/jonathan/organizor/spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

I havent done rails testing. This is my first time. I certainly know that some config I have missed. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is amazing, I had a empty file in lib directory called, "active_record.rb", this was being loaded instead of rails ActiveRecord. Hence, the uninitialized name error. Guys, be careful what you name your classes that you are going to keep under lib. It overrides.

Gosh, ate one day to figure this out.